# Is there a mirror for different versions of each generation of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables?

Tags: windows-update, redistributable

Sometimes I have to hunt down older versions of a MSVC redistributable to troubleshoot version mis-matches.

The only way I've been able to do this is to reference microsoft's Overview pages for redists like [this one](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829760), find the versions there, and then try my luck with the odd 3rd party website mirroring it, *hoping* I don't get viruses.

Preferably I'd like to do the equivalent of this:

```
someUpdateTool.exe /install /kb1234567890
```

I've been having a hard time finding something like that, if it exists. I've found tools that can help with Windows Updates, but it seems like the kb lists they fetch don't include redists, or at least not all of them.